Simple functional particular solution for the Riccati equation
In deriving the generating function for permutation statistics, I encountered a Riccati equation that the generating function satisfies, but I am unable to find any simple functional particular solution to this equation.
\begin{equation}\label{genpeak}
        \frac{\partial A(x,y,z_1,z_2;t)}{\partial t}=A(x,y,z_1,z_2;t)^2+(at+x+y)A(x,y,z_1,z_2;t)+ayt+z_1,    
    \end{equation}
where $a=z_2-z_1$.

Maple finds a rather complicated general solution involving Kummer functions.  Why do you expect a "simple" solution?

I want to study its properties on the generating function。
